# What are the possible return values of TRUNCATE TABLE executed with Entity Framework's ExecuteSqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

What is the return value of the following code when the code failed to execute ?

```
_Dbcontext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
```

I know that the value on succeed will be `-1` but still don't know what  other values expected to return if anything goes wrong . 
The [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.113).aspx) from Microsoft said the return value of `ExecuteSqlCommand` is the result returned by the database after executing the command but what are the returned values of the command  `TRUNCATE`?

Comment: what is the returned value in case of failed execution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that the value on succeed will be -1 but still don't know what other values expected to return if anything goes wrong.

[`TRUNCATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql) either (A) succeeds or (B) generates an error.

In .NET, this translates to (A) a return value of -1 or (B) an exception being thown. Since exceptions interrupt the control flow, there is no return value in the latter case.